# App failure on Docker container: what to make out of this Wildfly logs?

Tags: java, docker, hash, wildfly, hmac

I am trying to run my app using Docker. I created a Dockerfile, built an image and then run a container with my app.

However, when I request for a data to be send, I got an error (403) - wrong hash, meaning access is denied beacuse authentication process failed (I use Hmac-SHA1 algorithm). The conection between my app and data provider is established correctly (code 200), I was just not allowed data access.

If I run app without Docker (I run Wildfly locally and deploy war artifact manually) everything works great - however when I compare both hashes used (Docker & locally) they are indeed different. Both requests are identical of course.

I will be grateful for any directions.

```
Dockerfile:

    FROM jboss/wildfly
    COPY target/invoices.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
    EXPOSE 8080 9990

Docker commands I use:
    docker build -t invoices:v1 .
    docker run -p 8080:8080 <imageID>

 Wildfly logs (Docker container):
    14:10:00,334 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /invoicesByDateView: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Wynik"] not found.
            at deployment.invoices.war//org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:471)
            at deployment.invoices.war//org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:618)
            at deployment.invoices.war//fileReaders.JsonParser.getList(JsonParser.java:30)
            at deployment.invoices.war//fileReaders.JsonParser$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getList(Unknown Source)
            at deployment.invoices.war//servlets.InvoicesByDateViewServlet.doPost(InvoicesByDateViewServlet.java:98)
            at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
            at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
            at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
            at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Maybe your request payload or header is missing something as mentioned in the exception `JSONObject["Wynik"] not found. at deployment.invoices.war//org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:471)`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't thinks that the mother-error. Locally everythings works fine, and I get what I want. It only happens while running on Docker container. It looks like some kind of error while hashing request.

Comment: As JSONObject i receive is like that:  {"response":{"Code":403,"Information":"Wrong hash of sent message."}}

Comment: what happens if you try a simple get request? And please show me your request payload.

Comment: Ok. It was some kind of inaccuracy in Hmac-Sha1 algorithm and hexadecimal formats. It seems OK now. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, you fixed it. If possible you can put the solution to answer section.